# Web Intents don't work on Chrome 24.0.1312.14 beta and Chromium 25.0.1329.0 (168457) - how to fix?

Tags: google-chrome, webintents

I'm trying to run the web intent at http://examples.webintents.org/intents/shorten/shorten.html  but it is not working.

My OS is :  OS 10.7.5

Chrome/Chromium versions

1. Chrome 24.0.1312.14 beta
2. Chromium 25.0.1329.0 (168457)

In fact no web intents work for me at all.
Javascript console shows no errors.

What do I need to do to get web intents working on Chrome or Chromium?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web intents [are now disabled](https://plus.google.com/116171619992010691739/posts/gcXURKLN8bg) as of Chrome 24... (don't ask me why :/)